# Submitting a form using jQuery and Ajax changing the action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form, which I am trying to submit using jQuery and AJAX. I am triggering the submit by clicking on a link, which I've added an onclick method. Below are two code samples to submit the same form - the first works, but isn't AJAX, while the second method gives me a 404 error.

```
function submitmyform(formid) {
    $(formid).submit();
}
```

The second example attempts to use AJAX, given the same parameters:

```
function submitmyformajax(formid) {
    $.post({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(formid).attr('action'),
        data: $(formid).serialize(),
        success: function(data) { alert(data); }
    });
}
```

An alternate way I tried with the submitmyformajax is:

```
function submitmyformajax(formid) {
    $.post({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'somehardcoded/url',
        data: $(formid).serialize(),
        success: function(data) { alert(data); }
    });
}
```

For some reason, this continues to give me a 404 error, though the action on the form is correct (the URL it shows me is not the same as the action on the form).

I checked the error console, and it shows the 404 error as pointing to `somehardcoded/[object%20Object]` instead of what I specified in the method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried using both the method shown above and writing the URL directly into the function. However, when it submits, it replaces the end of my URL with [object%20Object] on the ajax version. Using the non-ajax version works correctly.

Comment: looks like your string url is not correct. put a breakpoint on the function and then evaluate what $(formid).attr('action') resolves to. I bet it isnt what you expect

Comment: It's exactly what I expect it to be... but when it submits, and I check the console, it's incorrect. I've also tried manually specifying the URL, and, as I indicated in a prior comment, it seems to change the end of the URL on submit to [object%20Object].

Comment: How is `submitmyformajax` called?

Comment: The same way I called submitmyform() - by putting a call to it in an onclick method.

Comment: I suspect is the serialize issue here, try to  `console.log($(formid).serialize())`, and see what inside, and also check what is the value for `formid`

Comment: Is there any other code on the page that is changing the jQuery Ajax code?

Comment: Ok, the URL includes an array of form elements, which are all named someval[]. Those are all being translated to someval%5B%5D

Comment: you doesn't need to include the `type: "POST"`, as `$.post` is already passing it as post

Comment: ok - what worked was switching it to .ajax, and leaving the rest alone. I'm still not sure why the URL was getting butchered, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting `$.post` and `$.ajax` mixed up. `$.post` is short hand for `$.ajax`, as such takes a string url as first parameter, an object as the data, and a function as the callback. `$.ajax` on the otherhand takes an object as configuration, as you are doing

i.e. Post signature is

```
$.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

which is shorthand for

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

You seem to be using a mixture of both, and hence getting strange behavior, as it is calling toString on the first parameter you are passing in to the `$.post` which is `[object Object]` and then that is url encoded to `[object%20Object]`

Either use

```
$.post($(formid).attr('action'),
       $(formid).serialize(),
       function(data) { alert(data); })
```

or

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(formid).attr('action'),
        data: $(formid).serialize(),
        success: function(data) { alert(data); }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! It was driving me nuts, but I couldn't see what I was doing wrong. Switching the one word post to ajax did the trick, and thanks for the explanation of the behaviour I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead..

```
$.post(
  'somehardcoded/url',
  {data:$(formid).serialize()},
  function(data) { 
    alert(data); 
  }
);
```